# Working with range and set value for found cell

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my procedure and I am newbie at VBA, I always find the struggle to work with such type of misstake.

Please help me.

```
Sub findsub()
Dim t As Range
Dim j As Range
Set j = Range("j1")

If j Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print "please enter the number"
Else
Set t = Range("G2:G19").Find("j1", LookIn:=xlValues)
Range("J4").Value = t.Offset(0, 1).Value '<-- ERROR HERE

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the result you are getting ? What is the expected result ? Do you get any error ??

Answer (score 1):

`j` cannot be Nothing, because in your code you are assigning it to something here:

```
Set j = Range("j1")
```

On the contrary, `t` can be `Nothing` if it is not found through the `.Find`

Thus:

```
Option Explicit
Sub findsub()

    Dim t As Range
    Dim j As Range

    Set j = Range("j1")
    Set t = Range("G2:G19").Find("j1", LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not t Is Nothing Then
        Range("J4").Value = t.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Long story short, search in the internet for "NULL, EMPTY, NOTHING, MISSING vba" and read some articles for it. Like this one:
http://allenbrowne.com/vba-NothingEmpty.html

Comment: The thing is [Range("J4").Value = t.Offset(0, 1).Value ] is not accepted. This is where I am struggling.

The outcome is nothing.

Comment: @PhạmTâm - "`t` can be `Nothing` if it is not found through the `.Find`."

Answer (score 1):

may be you're after something like this (explanations in comments)

```
Option Explicit

Sub findsub()
    Dim t As Range, j As Range

    Set j = Range("J1")

    If IsEmpty(j) Then ' if cell J1 is empty
        Debug.Print "please enter the number in cell J1"
    Else
        Set t = Range("G2:G19").Find(j.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) ' always explicitly define  both LookIn and LookAt parameters otherwise those from last Find call (even from UI) will be used 
        If Not t Is Nothing Then Range("J4").Value = t.Offset(0, 1).Value ' write in J4 if successfully found J1 value in range G2:G19
    End If
End Sub
```